# How to move a table that you have on your excel table from a query?

Tags: excel, powerquery

I hope you are well.

I have gone to data then from web, then I pasted the URL chose the location on the excel file I wanted to load it but how could I do to move the table generated by the query to another place on the same sheet or onto a new one without using cut?

Thanks

Comment: When you checked the Close & Load Drop down, didn't you got the Import Data window which gives you the option choose either Existing sheet or New Sheet, if you select the existing sheet, there will be an option to place the cell in the sheet where you want the data to be shown

Comment: Yes, I went on the dropdown menu of load and I select existing location to put it on the same sheet I was working on but on another occasion I did not do so, then I had to manually cut and paste the table onto the tab I wanted

Comment: See even if you don't select anything, the query will be showing you as a connection, when you click the `Data` tab --> `Queries & Connections` Panel opens on the right hand side, just right click the query you will get the option `Load To` select it, which again opens `Import Data` window, select `Table` next from where do you want to put the table, select existing worksheet and enter cell number and press Ok